# difference between variance and covariance

Tags: probability, terminology

What exactly is the physical interpretation of variance (in terms of a data set) and the difference between variance and co-variance matrices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The physical interpretation of **variance** is "how spread the data is". The higher the variance - the data is more spread. There is no such things as a variance matrix.

The  **Covariance** is a measure of correlation between two variables. for $X,Y$ random variables (scalars) - $cov(X,Y) = E[(X-E[X])(Y-E[Y])]$, and is a scalar too. note that $var(X)=cov(X,X)=E[(X-E[X])^2]$.

lastly - a **Covariance matrix** is used for random vectors. for a single random vector $\bar{X}=[X_1,...,X_n]^T$, a covariance matrix (which can be seen as a variance matrix, but this is not the correct term) is defined as $cov(X)=E[(X-E[X])(X-E[X])^T]$. Note that the diagonal elements in this matrix are the variances of the random variables $X_1,...,X_n$.

For two random vectors $X,Y$, we define the Covariance between them as $cov(X,Y)=E[(X-E[X])(Y-E[Y])^T]$.

Comment: Thanks alot that helped. What exactly is coorelation? i.e. its physical interpretation..

Comment: correlation is the linear relation between two variables. for example, if $X,Y$ are two random variables with **positive** correlation, than if $X$ grows larger, $Y$ will grow larger as well (the amount is decided by the exact correlation coefficient). If $X,Y$ has **negative** correlation, than when $X$ grows larger, $Y$ will get smaller. if they have zero correlation, then we can't say anything about $Y$ when $X$ grows\gets smaller (for example - Y can get smaller and then larger when X reaches some size).